# Повторение Item в ListView (CustomAdapter)

Tags: getview, android, listview, java

Здравствуйте!

Делаю вывод ListView, всё хорошо до момента пока ListView не становится длинным и появляется скролл.

На экран помещается 13 строк, я пролистываю его дальше и элементы начинают повторяться:[image]

Вот после 13 должно идти дальше до 30.

В Адаптере это выглядит так:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        String str = items.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(contextAdapter).inflate(R.layout.test_item, parent, false);
            TextView tvText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test_item_text);
            TextView tvText2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test_item_text_2);
            if (tvText != null)  tvText.setText("str:" + str);
            if (tvText2 != null) tvText2.setText("position:" + position);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Если я вынесу из `if` кусок с поиском элементов в лэйауте, то всё будет почти хорошо:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        String str = items.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(contextAdapter).inflate(R.layout.test_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }
        TextView tvText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test_item_text);
        TextView tvText2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test_item_text_2);
        if (tvText != null)  tvText.setText("str:" + str);
        if (tvText2 != null) tvText2.setText("position:" + position);
        return v;
    }
```

[image]

Но проблема в том, что каждый раз, когда я листаю список, он перестраивает ВСЕ видимые на данном экране элементы. Как сделать так, что бы он 1 раз сделал рендер итема, а потом брал из "сохраненных"?

Comment: А в чём проблема закешировать? Вы не знаете, как это сделать, или где держать сохранённые элементы?

Comment: @VladD - да, не знаю, вот наверное это и хотел узнать у сообщества.
Скорее так: идея про кеширование у меня конечно пришла, но это получился бы велосипед, ответ Романа Захарова - это видимо как раз то, что нужно!

Comment: @ua6xh: ну, если проблема с хранением и временем жизни решена, то заведите `Hashtable<int, View>`, перед тем, как создавать, посмотрите, нет ли в hashtable, а после создания добавьте в этот же hashtable. Стандартный кэш, в общем-то.

Comment: проблема в строке v = convertView;
После нее нужно вставить правильную инициализацию элементов. Она как раз и приводит к дублированию.

Comment: to @VladD

> то заведите Hashtable<int, View>

это очень плохой совет. Очень. Нельзя самостоятельно кешировать view для листвью.

Comment: листвью сам умеет хорошо кешировать свои item. если Вы пытаетесь это сделать вручную - получается плохо. Почему так - посмотрите [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) - там все рассказывают и растолковывают.

Comment: @KoVadim: вы отослали меня к видео длиной в час, это не очень честный аргумент. Расскажите лучше словами, хорошо? На мой наивный взгляд, если у Listview получится правильно, то и у меня тоже должно.

То, что Listview _может_ самостоятельно кешировать, не аргумент в пользу «Нельзя самостоятельно кешировать view для листвью» (а лишь аргумент в пользу «самостоятельно кешировать view для листвью неоптимально»).

Comment: попробую коротко. Но сложно часовое видео пересказать в 600 символов. Мне даже словами пол часа рассказывать.
Посмотрите видео. Там много хорошего. Я только раскажу, как в одной из программ, которую мне пришлось дописывать был подобный код. В листвью были элементы - картинка и две строки текста. Но вот только элементы регулярно дублировались (визуально). Выпиливание "рукотворного кеша" и использование правильных методов (которые я узнал с указанного видео) не только дало прирост отображения, но и убрало баги.

Comment: @KoVadim: А в чём всё же была проблема? Старый разработчик ошибся и неправильно кешировал, или правильно кешировать в принципе невозможно? Чем принципиально отличается кеширование «от Android'а» и то, что можно сделать руками? Есть какие-то внутренние события, на которые встроенный кеш правильно реагирует, а разработчику они не доступны?

(Извините, нету времени на часовое видео: Java и в частности Android — не моя платформа.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

почитайте про паттерн ViewHolder [здесь (п 6.3. Holder Pattern)](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_hoder)

Answer (score 0):

Так и хочется сказать как в [известной басне](http://enc-dic.com/word/k/Kak-ni-sadites-vse-v-muzkant-ne-godites-56085.html)...

В `getView()` должна использоваться концепция тегов, то есть в создаваемую `View` надо пихать т.н. тег/объект посредством `View.setTag()` и когда приходит ненулевой `convertView` извлекать оттуда объект через `View.getTag()` и выставлять объекту (в данном случае виджетам) нужные значения. Тогда не нужно будет каждый раз пересоздавать виджеты или наоборот работать с одним виджетом который и будет двоиться, троиться.

См. например [здесь](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) глава 6.4.

**P.S.** Да, [[@Роман Захаров](/users/8186/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)](/users/8186/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2) примерно об этом же и пишет...

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае я бы посоветовал не читайть эти ответы. Выкиньте все что вы сделали и сделайте ListView [по этому примеру](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html).